# I tried in google but its not relevant to my data

Tags: excel

I am trying to lookup data from other sheet. I have Two columns Column 1 with Numbers and Column 2 with names in **Sheet 2**. I placed a command button in the **Sheet 1** and Text box, so When i type the number in the text Box and when i click the command button it should display the name. Can any one help me with this.

Comment: Can you use a `VLookup`?

Comment: Try using `VLookup` or `Index Match`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `VLookup` formula

```
=VLOOKUP(2,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$5,2,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in the click event of your button.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim result
    Dim txtBoxStr As Long

    'get text box value
    txtBoxStr = Val(Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox1.Value) 'change sheet name and text box name as required

    On Error Resume Next 'execution continues if error occurs
    result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(txtBoxStr, Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:B10"), 2, False) 'change sheet name and text box name as required
    On Error GoTo 0 'enabled error handler will be disabled

    If result = "" Then
        MsgBox "Number not found."
    Else
        MsgBox result
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, it was so use full. AND ALL WORKING NOW!!!!

Comment: @Harsshan - If this solved your problem kindly accept it as an answer.

Comment: May I know how to do that.

Comment: @Harsshan - Just click the tick button at the top left of the answer.

Comment: @Harsshan - See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).